# Setting Website meta description

Tags: php, html, meta

I am trying to set the website description to be displayed on google search. I have seen some tutorials and all have implemented it using meta-description tag. But using the same concept my website's description is not being successfully displayed.

On googling my website's name it is showing the text that is included in the website body. I want to show my custom text to be displayed in the website description.

Below is what i have done. Kindly let me know if I have missed something.

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"> 
<title>FuturoLicht - Tours And Travels </title>
<meta name="description" content="Travel through untouched expanses of India. Join the most promising India vacations tour offering you a treasure of golden memories. Travel to Goa, Kerala, Rajasthan, New Delhi, Mumbai (Bombay) and many more destinations to unfold the new possibilities in India.">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<!--<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.futurolicht.com/data7/images/spiti.jpg" />

<meta property="og:description" content="Travel through untouched expanses of India. Packed within each destination there are some pleasant surprises we have in store for you. Join the most promising India vacations tour offering you a treasure of golden memories. At Futuro Licht Tours, we believe that your needs are unique and we always look forward to create an equally unique and customized tour package as per your needs. We ensure that you experience all the richness and depths of the destinations of your choice, with a penchant for making every Guest's travel experience, a lifetime memory." />-->
```

Any Help would be appreciaated.

Comment: Google has not read your updated "meta" tag. When the google crawler comes to website next time then it will read and updated his database and show on search result page Either manually submit your page to google.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RajivRanjan and how to submit my page manually to google crawler DB

Answer (score 4):

Google will not immediately start using your description tag, it will take some time for them to put your description in their results.